# GeoServer - Free Memory button

Tags: geoserver

Okay, so the Geoserver documentation (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/status.html#config-serverstatus) says that clicking on the “Free Memory” button, cleans up memory marked for deletion by running the garbage collector.

So my question is why have this button in the first place?  Why isn't the GC being run automatically?  I am having to periodically click this button to improve performance, and that seems kind of lame.

I'm using the Concurrent Mark Sweep garbage collector as per the Geoserver "Container Considerations" help topic recommendation: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#optimize-your-jvm

Comment: There should be no reason to run GC manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086800/java-garbage-collection. Perhaps you have some specific problem in your installation.

Comment: This is mostly a debugging aid for developers. May be you can elaborate on the performance issues and your setup in a new question.

Comment: It's just that the Memory Usage value on the Server Status screen never goes down unless I click the Free Memory button.  Doesn't seem like GC is being run.